# Get value of HTML textbox and pass it to PHP function while page is loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a project for school and here is my problem:
I know that these kind of apps must be written in JavaScript but our professor wants it written in PHP, I have a `textbox` and I change its value with JavaScript using the key pressing event and in it I stock 4 variables ( up , down , left , right ) only by pressing the directions keys on my keyboard (not by writing them ), now my problem is that I can't find a way to pass the value of this `textbox` to a PHP function on the same page while the page is loading (the page contains an infinite loop with the PHP function inside).

Any ideas please?

```
<?php
include "TableClass.php";
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jeu du serpent - Arene</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", touche, false); //defining the event
 // the function whish change the value of the text box by cliquing the directions keys on keybord
function touche(event) {                           
    var textbox = document.getElementById('hid');
    var touche = event.keyCode;
    if (touche == 37) {
        textbox.value = 'vers_gauche';
    }
    if (touche == 38) {
        textbox.value = 'vers_le_haut';
    }
    if (touche == 39) {
        textbox.value = 'vers_droite';
    }
    if (touche == 40) {
        textbox.value = 'vers_le_bas';
    }
}

</script>
<body>
//the text box whish i want to get it value
<input id="hid" type="text" value="vers_le_bas">
<?php     
    if (isset($_POST['valide'])) {

$Arene = new Tableau(1, $_POST['taille']);
$Arene->ImprimerTableau();

while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    // I WANT THE VALUE OF THE TEXT BOX in the argument of this method
    // while the page is still loading
    $Arene->modifierDierectionserpent($direction);
    $Arene->ImprimerTableau();       
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not pass value to some php function on same page while it is loading because variables will be empty, textbox will be filled with value once you click left right etc as you have mentioned.. so you have to trigger some action and in that action pass the values to the function.

Comment: i didn't follow you mate !! can you explain more please ?